# Start multiple programs using Powershell without leaving the window open afterward

Tags: powershell

I want to load a series of programs and then have the PowerShell instance close afterward. This is what I have:

```
Start-Process -FilePath <path to chrome>
Start-Process -FilePath <path to firefox>
Start-Process -FilePath <path to vs code>
```

So basically, I want to run it like a batch file where it launches the listed programs and then goes away. But instead, it leaves the powershell window open and if I manually close it, VScode shuts too (the browsers stay open for some reason).

I see there's a -wait option for start-process, but I want the opposite: -nowait. Just open and go away. How can I do this? The other commands like invoke and startjob don't seem right.

Comment: How are you executing the script?

Comment: Can you give more details, ideally a [mcve] for us to try and reproduce?

Answer (score 1):

Since these are GUI applications, you don't need to worry about using
`Start-Process -Wait:$False`; GUI applications don't block in PowerShell (or Command Prompt) by default. You can simply run those programs with the call-operator `&` (technically optional to use the call-operator but it covers the path-with-spaces case):

```
& "\path\to\guiprogram.exe"
```

If you need to do this with a non-GUI application, then you would need to use
`Start-Process -Wait:$False` (or omit `-Wait` altogether since `Start-Process` doesn't block by default) to continue executing:

```
Start-Process -Wait:$False "\path\to\program.exe"
Start-Process "\path\to\program.exe"
```

---

`-SwitchParameter:$Value` syntax allows you to set the explicit value of `[switch]` parameters. *Usually* the switch parameter is implicitly managed. It is in an "on (true)" state if provided, and an "off (false)" state when omitted.

However, you can explicitly set the value of a switch parameter by suffixing the parameter with `:$Value`. The value's truthiness will be evaluated and the switch state will match "on" for `$True` and "off" for `$False`.